# Develop my own XHTML namespace

Tags: html, xhtml

I would like to ask if it is possible to develop my own XHTML namespace similar to Facebook FBML.

I want to have different tags for displaying boards (similar to fb:board), internalization tags (similar to fb:intl) and more.

Any starting guide/points will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to ask if it is possible to develop my own XHTML namespace

No, there is only one XHTML namespace.

> similar to Facebook FBML.

That's an XML namespace, and yes you can.

> Any starting guide/points will be appreciated

Namespaces are a [W3C recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/)

Comment: Can you provide a guide line for XML namespace? Or is it better to start a new question?

Comment: There is already a link in my answer. There really isn't much to namespaces.